# How to increase the gain of Operational transconductance amplifier by changing the sizes of transistors.

Tags: amplifier, analog, cmos, ota

Here is the schematics of the OTA. [image]

By changing the length of the transistors I am having more gain but I cannot reach the gain of 200. The maximum gain I reach is 110.35. I want to reach the gain of 200 only by changing the sizes of the transistors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your voltage gain will be

$$
\frac {V_{net3}} {V_{INP}-V_{INN}} = \frac {g_{m2}} {g_{ds2}+g_{ds5}}
$$

Assuming the NET3 is your output. Since for a given current density gm is proportional to the DC current, (\$ gm = \frac {2 I_{DC}} {V_{GS}-V_{th}}\$) and in saturation gds is also proportional to the DC current (\$ g_{ds}=\lambda*I_{DC}\$), the intrinsic gain of the transistors of your technology limits your gain. You can not change the intrinsic gain, but you can use an additional stage or stages to increase the gain. For example cascoding, where the second stage is a common gate stage.

Comment: But what about channel length modulation ?

Comment: Have you examined using Longer Channel PFETs?

Comment: yes , but I reach very high lengths like 1000 micro meter. And can't understand how to keep the ration to reach the desired gain.

Comment: Take a SINGLE NCHANNEL, and impose a constant-current SPICE load. That is the maximum gain you can get.

Comment: At channel lengths you have in the picture it does not play a role at all. 
Looking at the picture again I think you are in deep subthreshold region. Is it intended? You must barely have any gm.

Comment: @HorrorVacui I have a gm when I increase the length of the transistor. I have increased the length of nmos and pmos by more than 210 times and I had a gain of more than 200 on the linear part of the output.